# Should questions asking for one view be asked again but for a different view?

Tags: discussion, support

This [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/why-divorce-does-not-require-witnesses-shia-view) originally was asking for the Sunni view, now it is asking for the Shia view.  Would opening a whole new question asking for a different view be ok, or would it be called a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

I believe it has merit, especially if most of the answers in the original question have not touched on that view. BTW, SE actually encourages duplicate questions, which should not necessarily be closed. Although it's usually better to consolidate answers into one place, sometimes it's useful to have them divided over a clear borderline.

Comment: @AlUmmat I divided the answers into too to allow people to vote on both answers separately. Some may support the different view option, but may not support the uneducated argument.

Comment: ok I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The asker should select only one answer as "Accepted". If someone asks some Fiqh question, and is seeking both Sunni and Shia answers, which one should be accepted? Even if there are multiple Fatwa in Sunnah or Shia, which one should be accepted?

The best strategy is to have the same question that asks all views, and the same accepted answer that also lists all different view. However for many cases this would be impractical and very long questions/answers.

So I think it's necessary to permit multiple questions of the similar topic but asking different views.

Answer (score -1):

There is also the possibility that an old question received a number of uneducated answers, and after months the OP thinks that our community is now more capable of answering that question. I think this case should be permitted too, although the new question should be closed as duplicate if it does not succeed in attracting such educated answers within a few days.

Comment: Drawing attention to the old question by either improving it (insofar as bad answers are often a sign of a poorly-written question) or by offering a bounty is typically better than intentionally posting a duplicate.  Not to say that duplicates don't [have their place](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), they just shouldn't be the first (or only) resort.